# overriding "prepare for segue" when programmatically creating a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift4, uistoryboardsegue

I have a `UIView`, inside it I'm creating a `UIViewController`:

```
class TopBarView: UIView {
    var viewController: UIViewController?{
        didSet{
           print("a")
    }
}
```

later in my code, I'm performing a `segue` using:

```
if let vc = viewController {
    vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "imagesSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

I wish to pass some parameters to the `UIViewController` I'm performing the `segue` to.

I tried to add a "prepare for segue" definition inside the definition of the `viewcontroller`, so it would look like this:

```
class TopBarView: UIView {
    var viewController: UIViewController?{
        didSet{
           print("a")
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error - such a thing probably cannot be done.

How can I pass the required parameters into the new `UIViewController`?

Comment: `class TopBarView: UIView` It's from a UIView, not a UIViewController, since UIView doesn't declare it, you aren't overriding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   /////
}
```

Should be inside the vc that you assign to `var viewController: UIViewController?`  and use `sender` parameter to send any data

```
vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "imagesSegue", sender:"someStr")
```

> Note: You can't use a segue if the vc is created programmatically